# How to pass error message from batch file to team city

Tags: batch-file, teamcity

I am executing a batch file inside team city build step. batch file has this code.

```bat
if errorlevel NEQ 0 (
        echo ##teamcity[message text='failed' errorDetails='' status='ERROR']
        exit 1
)
```

%errorlevel% just provides error level. How can I get error message so that I can pass that to team city message service.

Comment: Try `If ErrorLevel 1 (` or `If Not "%ErrorLevel%" == "0" (`

Comment: What command line causes the error (and thus `ErrorLevel`)? does it provide the error message at _STDERR_? you could try something like [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) `"delims=" %%E in ('teamcity ... 2>&1 > nul') do @echo Message: %%E`...

Comment: @aschipfl I do see error message in STDERR.  There is no issue with batch it runs successfully. I am trying to test scenario in case batch fail, Message should be display in team city as error. Right now error output is being displayed inside teamcity build output in gray color.

Comment: @aschipfl Inside as folder I have few .sql files. Each file is called a procedure with different parameters and checking result. if result not matching expected value script throws error. Basically these .sql files are test cases. Using batch file I am executing each .sql file present inside folder.

Comment: @aschipfl What I want is if .sql file  fails I need to report failure to team city. This batch file is kind of teamcity-test-reporter.

Comment: Well, this is quite some information spread over several comments; would you mind to [edit] your question and make it clear to everyone?

Answer (score 1):

you should pass  inside double quotes 
`echo "##teamcity[message text='failed' errorDetails='' status='ERROR']"`

If you want to add error information to the build problems just use below: 
`echo "##teamcity[buildProblem description='Some conditions return an error' status='ERROR']"`